# What do these bags make?

Tags: part-identification

I am trying to organize my sons LEGO bricks and we cannot find a book or what these bags go to. Not even sure the bags go together?

Bag 5 has grey pieces and these long red things that look like you shoot them at something.

[image]

This bag has yellow wheels and lots of other grey, red and yellow and some black

[image]

Bag 2 with yellow and grey and black and little red and maybe two blue also a grey clear windshield piece

[image]

This bag has lots of grey light and dark and some red tan and black in it and a couple blue small ones

[image]

Comment: Hello Gwendolyn, welcome to bricks.stackexchange! I've taken the liberty to merge your answers with your original post and flagged the answers for deletion. To your question: it looks like bags 5 and 4 belong to the same set - a Star Wars vehicle - and bags 2 and 3 also seem to belong together but as part of a different set.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that you don't have any complete sets - the numbers are which order you are supposed to open them in order to complete the set, so since you have no #1 bags, there isn't really any place to get started with them

Comment: Ya, these were just random bags I had leftover after organizing. Trying to figure out which sets they go with. I organized about 60 different sets today so it's a complete mess!!

Answer (score 6):

Bags 4 and 5 are from set [75050-1: B-Wing](http://brickset.com/sets/75050-1/B-Wing) based on the red [Arrow 8M For Spring Shooter](http://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6054526), [4211725: Plate 4X6 26 Degrees](http://brickset.com/parts/4211725) and [4233485: Brick 1X2 With Cross Hole](http://brickset.com/parts/4233485)

Bags 2 & 3 are from [4202-1: Mining Truck](http://brickset.com/sets/4202-1/Mining-Truck) based on [4210720: Plate 6X14](http://brickset.com/parts/4210720), [4210794: Plate 6X8](http://brickset.com/parts/4210794)
, [4490139: Rim Wide W.Cross 30X20](http://brickset.com/parts/4490139)
, [4188313: Coupling Plate 2X2](http://brickset.com/parts/4188313) and [4515351: Plate 4X4 Round W. Snap](http://brickset.com/parts/4515351)
 in combination with the different red parts